# Primefaces 5 + JSF 2.2 Argument Error: Parameter key is null

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I get `Parameter key is null` error when I click `commendlink/button` of `Primefaces 5` dialog(Dialog Framework).

mainpage.xthml

```
    <p:commandLink immediate="true" actionListener="#{ManageProgrammerActionBean.selectDepartment()}">
        <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{ManageProgrammerActionBean.returnDepartment}" update="departmentPanel" />
        <p:graphicImage url="/images/search.png" style="height:30px;width:30px" />
    </p:commandLink>
```

dialogpage.xhtml

```
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/common/dialogTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <p:dataTable var="department" value="#{DepartmentDialogActionBean.departmentList}" id="departmentTable" paginator="true" rows="10" style="width:100%;" widgetVar="departmentTable"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10, 15"
                rowIndexVar="index">
                <p:column headerText="No" style="width:50px;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{index + 1}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Name">
                    <h:outputText value="#{department.name}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Description">
                    <h:outputText value="#{department.description}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Add Your Custom Column">
                    <h:outputText value="" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:30px;text-align: center;">
                    <p:commandLink action="#{DepartmentDialogActionBean.selectDepartment(department)}" immediate="true">
                        <h:graphicImage url="/images/select.png" styleClass="action-img" />
                    </p:commandLink>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

stacktrace

```
18:22:59,516 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-25) java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter key is null: javax.fa
ces.FacesException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter key is null
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:276) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:927) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter.doFilter(FacesExceptionFilter.java:56) [omnifaces-1.7.jar:1.7]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:77) [omnifaces-1.7.jar:1.7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15
.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.
Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Fin
al.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.1
5.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter key is null
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.notNull(Util.java:448) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap.get(SessionMap.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.commandlink.CommandLink.queueEvent(CommandLink.java:219) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorRenderer.decode(AjaxBehaviorRenderer.java:47) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.ClientBehaviorBase.decode(ClientBehaviorBase.java:132) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.decodeBehaviors(CoreRenderer.java:492) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.commandlink.CommandLinkRenderer.decode(CommandLinkRenderer.java:50) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:831) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1225) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:590) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1690) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:406) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:269) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: this is a [defect](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6978)

Answer (score 1):

First you should prevent using the same name for id and widgetVar.

Then try to use a binding in your dataTable.

```
<p:dataTable ....  binding="#{DepartmentDialogActionBean.dataTable}" .... />
```

your java file:

```
class DepartmentDialogActionBean {

    private DataTable dataTable;

    public DataTable getDataTable() {
         return dataTable
    }

    public void setDataTable(DataTable t) {
         dataTable = t;
    }

    public void selectDepartment() {
        Department dep = (Department) dataTable.getRowData();
        //do anthing with dep
    }
```

}

Should be the easiest way to access data out of dataTable!

Comment: my method is `public void selectDepartment(Department dep)..`.

Comment: Where is your department coming from? there has to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue using a command button inside a tree table (primefaces 5.3). I used widgetVar for the command button. which the render engine generates multiples of it, causing this error message. When removed widgetvar attribute the problem was resolved.
Instead of using widget var you can use id attribute and use it from the managed bean like this:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent('componentID');
```